# Can href be used to get css format for an jsp file in Eclipse?

Tags: java, jsp

I am writing a JSP program and would like to apply css that I placed in WEB-INF file to the mypage.jsp. But when I use href the css is not applied. Here's my code inside the mypage.jsp:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="WEB-INF/assets/css/styles_main.css">
```

If this is wrong, how can I apply css to jsp in Eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything placed inside WEB-INF is not accessible from the outside. Put your CSS anyywhere you want, but not under WEB-INF.

Comment: that is hilarious, out of all the places I chose to put it into one place that is not accessible, thanks JB!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, correct put your Link into your header in Jsp, and put it in WebContent.